# How do I Binding Data from Resource data into Blade Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I Have a Controller Like This

```
public function print(Request $request)
    {
        $id =  explode(',',$request->id);
       
        $data = DeliveryOrder::whereIn('id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        $dataku =  DeliveryOrderResource::collection($data);
        
        // return $dataku;
         return view('warehouse.printdo', compact('dataku'));
    }
```

If I return the `$dataku`,..

[image: Data Json]

and then I Will bind the Data into Blade Laravel, but i get an error

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: ,...resources\views\warehouse\printdo.blade.php)
```

[image: ppl]

Comment: please provide code as text not an image ... why are you passing a resouce to a view?

Comment: with resource I can display detailed data from various models easily, ..

Comment: Remove the first foreach. Change `row->do_details` to `$dakatu->do_details` in 2nd foreach.

Answer (score 0):

As you provided the screenshot, you have `do_details` in first `array`.

what if you don't have `do_details` in the second array?

You need to check the condition the foreach you're using have data or not.

```
@if(!empty($row->do_details))
    @foreach($row->do_details as $do => $detOrder)
    //additional code
    @endforeach 
@endif
```